# newtag for my equation-environment

Tags: environments, equation-number

I would like to create a newtag for my equation-environment

```
\NewEnviron{MyEq}{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}
```

with this tag: $\mathbb D$.number-of-my-equation. For example

```
\begin{MyEq}
A+B=C\tag{\mathbb{D}.1}
\end{MyEq}
```

Is it possible? Thank you so much.

**First Edit:** I'd like to have something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newtagform{D}{$\mathbb{D}$.}{}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand{\myeq}[2]{%
    \setcounter{mycount}{\value{equation}} % save current eq. nnumber
    \setcounter{equation}{#1}
    \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
    \usetagform{D}        % switch to special tag form
    \begin{equation} #2 \end{equation}
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{mycount}} % restore eq. nnumber
    \usetagform{default}% % restore default tag form
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}0+0=0\end{equation}
\myeq{1}{1+1=2}
\begin{equation}2+2=4\end{equation}
\myeq{2}{1+2=3}

\end{document}
```

but in this form or in an equivalent one:

```
%Preamble...
\begin{equation}0+0=0\end{equation}
\begin{myeq}0+0=0\end{myeq}
\begin{equation}2+2=4\end{equation}
\begin{myeq}1+2=3\end{myeq}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need `\NewEnviron` when the replacement text does nothing with `\BODY` 2. Should the number be independent of the standard `equation` counter?

Comment: Yes, the tag of MyEq should be $\mathbb D$.number-of-my-equation.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't answer. Do you have equations with the standard tag form and also others with the different one? Should the numbering be the same? So if the first new tag form comes after equation 4, should it be D.1 or D.5?

Comment: The counter with "D" is completely independent to the standard counter. In your case, **egreg**, the answer is D.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\NewEnviron` unless you need to do something with `\BODY` (and, nowadays, there's the `b` argument type to `\NewDocumentEnvironment`).

Just set up what you need and issue a suitable `\tag` command before closing the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcounter{Dequation}
\newenvironment{Dequation}
 {\stepcounter{Dequation}\begin{equation}}
 {\tag*{$\mathbb{D}$.\theDequation}\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

Some text and a standard equation
\begin{equation}\label{a}
1=1
\end{equation}
Some text and a D equation
\begin{Dequation}\label{b}
2=2
\end{Dequation}
Some text and a standard equation
\begin{equation}\label{c}
1=1
\end{equation}
Some text and a D equation
\begin{Dequation}\label{d}
2=2
\end{Dequation}
Some final text; \ref{a}, \eqref{a};
\ref{b}, \eqref{b};
\ref{c}, \eqref{c};
\ref{d}, \eqref{d}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Remark*: I rewrote the answer after the OP left a comment that the "D" equations should be numbered consecutively, starting with `(\mathbb{D}.1)`.

Here's a solution that employs the `\tag` macro that's provided by the `amsmath` package. "D"-equations can be cross-referenced using the standard LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` mechanism. Do note, though, that the `\label` directive has to placed in the argument of `\myeq`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\tag' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\mathbb' macro
\newcounter{mycount}  % counter for 'D'-type equations
\newcommand{\myeq}[1]{%
    \[ 
    \stepcounter{mycount} 
    #1
    \tag{$\mathbb{D}$.\arabic{mycount}}
    \]
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}0+0=0\end{equation}
\myeq{1+1=2\label{eq:D1}}
\begin{equation}2+2=4\end{equation}
\myeq{3+3=6\label{eq:D2}}
A cross-reference to equation \eqref{eq:D1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico for your answer. But I'd like that the #1 be automatic. How can I do? Thank you again

Comment: I believe that both `\tag` and `\refstepcounter` will add an anchor, if `hyperref` is used. In any case, `\stepcounter` is what you want.